# How do you put pins on Google maps?

Tags: android

Is there a way to mark certain location on android google map like how you can put pins on iPhone apple maps and if so, can you show me or tell me how. I am new to android development and would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use a  [GeoPoint](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint&ei=Mgx_UMvFOIXriAfc_ICoDg&usg=AFQjCNE9Ge6XUQq7rQeNUDrHGFYchWRN-w&sig2=D2GmRJjkir5NBfPLwj8WVQ). Have a look at this tutorial for help on making a mapping app. [TUTORIAL](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview&ei=Nwx_UNOxAqiSiAfBxoAQ&usg=AFQjCNEfQhQMJEv3LSLy872-2zBlvQ4INA&sig2=QTwtOWhzcYbB-6wmptoaxQ)

Comment: If this answer helped you, mark as correct to help other users find the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, putting a pointer on a map is fairly easy.  Basically, you start with a very basic app.  Instead of extending `Activity`, you extend `MapActivity`.  You can then start the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview) to create a basic GUI.

Unfortunately, getting a map up and running takes a bit of work.  Before you can even see a map, you need a Google Maps API key.  It's explained in the documentation, but it can be a bit confusing.  [Here](http://blog.simplyadvanced.net/developers-how-to-get-the-androidgoogle-maps-api-key/) is a great tutorial explaining how to get an API key.

Once you have a key, you can fire up the example code from the tutorial.  Make sure you have a data connection or else you won't see the map tiles.  In addition, make sure you have internet permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file.  You also need to paste your new API key into your `MapView` XML code.  The tutorial explains all of this quite nicely.

Once you have all that set up, it's easy enough to add a geographic coordinate to the map.  I could explain it here, but Google does a good enough job on the subject.  Follow their directions on how to create an `ItemizedOverlay` class.  Then find the coordinates of your house or something and see it on the map.

Good luck!